# What ReSharper 4+ live templates for C# do you use?

Tags: c#, templates, refactoring, resharper

What ReSharper 4.0 templates for **C#** do you use?

Let's share these in the following format:

---

### [Title]

*Optional description*

**Shortcut:** shortcut
**Available in:** [AvailabilitySetting]

```
// Resharper template code snippet
// comes here
```

**Macros properties** (if present):

- **Macro1** - Value - EditableOccurence
- **Macro2** - Value - EditableOccurence

---

- One macro per answer, please!
- Here are some samples for [NUnit test fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186970/what-resharper-40-templates-for-c-do-you-use#186978) and [Standalone NUnit test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186970/what-resharper-40-templates-for-c-do-you-use#186978) that describe live templates in the suggested format.

Comment: Should this be on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) instead because it’s subjective?

Comment: This question is not constructive and there is a lot of information out there about resharper live templates and visual studio templates. http://programmingsolved.blogspot.com/2014/04/snippet-away.html

Answer (score 31):

### Simple Lambda

So simple, so useful - a little lambda:

**Shortcut**: x

**Available**: C# where expression is allowed.

```
x => x.$END$
```

Macros: none.

Answer (score 22):

### Implement 'Dispose(bool)' Method

*Implement [Joe Duffy's Dispose Pattern](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2005/04/08/DGUpdateDisposeFinalizationAndResourceManagement.aspx)*

**Shortcut:** dispose

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if ($MEMBER$ != null)
            {
                $MEMBER$.Dispose();
                $MEMBER$ = null;
            }
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
}

~$CLASS$()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

private bool disposed;
```

**Macros properties**:

- **MEMBER** - Suggest variable of System.IDisposable - Editable Occurence #1
- **CLASS** - Containing type name

Answer (score 14):

### Create new unit test fixture for some type

**Shortcut:** ntf
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration or namespace declaration is allowed

```
[NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute]
public sealed class $TypeToTest$Tests
{
    [NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute]
    public void $Test$()
    {
        var t = new $TypeToTest$()
        $END$
    }
}
```

**Macros:**

- **TypeToTest** - none - #2
- **Test** - none - V

Answer (score 13):

### Check if a string is null or empty.

*If you're using .Net 4 you may prefer to use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace().*

**Shortcut**: sne

**Available in**: C# 2.0+ where expression is allowed.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty($VAR$)
```

**Macro properties**:

- VAR - suggest a variable of type string. Editible = true.

Answer (score 11):

### Create new stand-alone unit test case

**Shortcut:** ntc
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
[NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute]
public void $Test$()
{
    $END$
}
```

**Macros:**

- **Test** - none - V

Answer (score 10):

Declare a log4net logger for the current type.

**Shortcut:** log

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof($TYPE$));
```

**Macros properties**:

- **TYPE** - Containing type name

Comment: With re-sharper, why not use this? private static readonly ILog _Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof($CurrType$)); with $CurrType$:Containing type name

Comment: Because if I change the type name later on I would have to update that line of code as well.  Mine is more dynamic.

Comment: ReSharper automatically renames all instances of a type name. GetType() is slower too.

Answer (score 9):

### MS Test Unit Test

*New MS Test Unit test using AAA syntax and the naming convention found in the [Art Of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/)*

**Shortcut:** testing (or tst, or whatever you want)
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
[TestMethod]
public void $MethodName$_$StateUnderTest$_$ExpectedBehavior$()
{
    // Arrange
    $END$

    // Act


    // Assert

}
```

**Macros properties** (if present):

- **MethodName** - The name of the method under test
- **StateUnderTest** - The state you are trying to test
- **ExpectedBehavior** - What you expect to happen

Answer (score 8):

### Check if variable is null

**Shortcut:** ifn
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files

```
if (null == $var$)
{
    $END$
}
```

### Check if variable is not null

**Shortcut:** ifnn
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files

```
if (null != $var$)
{
    $END$
}
```

Comment: How did that transition from C++ to C# treat you?

Comment: Goes well w/ 'Execute smart completion' as macro for $var$

Comment: Nice "Yoda Conditions"!! ... unwise this way of coding is ;-))

Answer (score 7):

**Assert.AreEqual**

*Simple template to add asserts to a unit test*

**Shortcut**: ae
**Available in**: in C# 2.0+ files where statement is allowed

```
Assert.AreEqual($expected$, $actual$);$END$
```

Fluent version :

```
Assert.That($expected$, Is.EqualTo($actual$));$END$
```

Answer (score 7):

### Write StyleCop-compliant summary for class constructor

*(if you are tired of constantly typing in long standard summary for every constructor so it complies to StyleCop rule SA1642)*

**Shortcut:** csum

**Available in:** C# 2.0+

```
Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="$classname$"/> class.$END$
```

**Macros:**

- **classname** - Containing type name - V

Answer (score 7):

### Lots of Lambdas

Create a lambda expression with a different variable declaration for easy nesting.

**Shortcut:** la, lb, lc

**Available in:** C# 3.0+ files where expression or query clause is allowed

*la* is defined as:

```
x => x.$END$
```

*lb* is defined as:

```
y => y.$END$
```

*lc* is defined as:

```
z => z.$END$
```

This is similar to Sean Kearon above, except I define multiple lambda live templates for easy nesting of lambdas. "*la*" is most commonly used, but others are useful when dealing with expressions like this:

```
items.ForEach(x => x.Children.ForEach(y => Console.WriteLine(y.Name)));
```

Comment: is it ok to use x,y names for lambda arguments? if you have two-three level nested lambdas, you probably don't want to memorize what does x,y,z means at each level. Considering your example, I would go with items.ForEach(item => ... and item.Children.ForEach(child => ... so that at the end I would have child.Name instead of y.Name. I don't think naming for lambdas arguments can be treated similary to for loop indexes i,j,k

Answer (score 6):

### Wait for It...

Pause for user input before end of a console application.

**Shortcut:** pause

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where statement is allowed

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit...");
System.Console.ReadLine();$END$
```

Comment: I'd use `Console.ReadKey(true);`, and allow any key to be pressed.

Answer (score 6):

**Dependency property generation**

*Generates a dependency property*

**Shortcut:** dp
**Available in:** C# 3.0 where member declaration is allowed

```
public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty $PropertyName$Property =
        System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register("$PropertyName$",
                                                   typeof ($PropertyType$),
                                                   typeof ($OwnerType$));

    public $PropertyType$ $PropertyName$
    {
        get { return ($PropertyType$) GetValue($PropertyName$Property); }
        set { SetValue($PropertyName$Property, value); }
    }

$END$
```

Macros properties (if present):

PropertyName - No Macro - #3
PropertyType - Guess type expected at this point - #2
OwnerType - Containing type name - no editable occurence

Answer (score 5):

### Quick ExpectedException Shortcut

Just a quick shortcut to add to my unit test attributes.

**Shortcut**: ee

**Available in**: Available in: C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
[ExpectedException(typeof($TYPE$))]
```

Comment: Just a quick note that it's been a couple version now that ExpectedException has been deprecated in NUnit in favor of using Assert.Throws<>

Comment: Yes please please everyone stop using ExpectedExceptionAttribute, still see devs using MSTest use this even today :-(

Answer (score 5):

### Notify Property Changed

*This is my favourite because I use it often and it does a lot of work for me.*

**Shortcut**: npc

**Available in**: C# 2.0+ where expression is allowed.

```
if (value != _$LOWEREDMEMBER$)
{
  _$LOWEREDMEMBER$ = value;
  NotifyPropertyChanged("$MEMBER$");
}
```

**Macros**:

- MEMBER - Containing member type name. Not editable. *Note: make sure this one is first in the list.*
- LOWEREDMEMBER - Value of MEMBER with the first character in lower case. Not editable.

**Usage**:
Inside a property setter like this:

```
private string _dateOfBirth;
public string DateOfBirth
{
   get { return _dateOfBirth; }
   set
   {
      npc<--tab from here
   }
}
```

It assumes that your backing variable starts with an "_".  Replace this with whatever you use.  It also assumes that you have a property change method something like this:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
   }
}
```

In reality, the version of this I use is lambda based ('cos I loves my lambdas!) and produces the below.  The principles are the same as the above.

```
public decimal CircuitConductorLive
{
   get { return _circuitConductorLive; }
   set { Set(x => x.CircuitConductorLive, ref _circuitConductorLive, value); }
}
```

That's when I'm not using the extremely elegant and useful [PostSharp to do the whole INotifyPropertyChanged thing for no effort](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/ui#data-binding), that is.

Answer (score 5):

### AutoMapper Property Mapping

**Shortcut:** fm

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where statement is allowed

```
.ForMember(d => d$property$, o => o.MapFrom(s => s$src_property$))
$END$
```

**Macros:**

- property - editable occurrence
- src_property - editable occurrence

**Note:**

I leave the lambda "dot" off so that I can hit . immediately and get property intellisense. 
  Requires AutoMapper (http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4):

### Create test case stub for NUnit

*This one could serve as a reminder (of functionality to implement or test) that shows up in the unit test runner (as any other ignored test),*

**Shortcut:** nts
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
[Test, Ignore]
public void $TestName$()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
$END$
```

Comment: I do a variation on this, but with explicit Assert.Fail() in the body:
http://aleriel.com/blog/2010/04/07/replace-paper-with-unit-tests/

Answer (score 4):

## Invoke if Required

Useful when developing WinForms applications where a method should be callable from non-UI threads, and that method should then marshall the call onto the UI thread.

**Shortcut**: inv

**Available in**: C# 3.0+ files statement is allowed

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke((System.Action)delegate { $METHOD_NAME$($END$); });
    return;
}
```

**Macros**

- **METHOD_NAME** - Containing type member name

---

You would normally use this template as the first statement in a given method and the result resembles:

```
void DoSomething(Type1 arg1)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke((Action)delegate { DoSomething(arg1); });
        return;
    }

    // Rest of method will only execute on the correct thread
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### MSTest Test Method

This is a bit lame but it's useful.  Hopefully someone will get some utility out of it.

Shortcut: testMethod

Available in: C# 2.0

```
[TestMethod]
public void $TestName$()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();

    //Arrange.

    //Act.

    //Assert.
}

$END$
```

Answer (score 4):

### NUnit Setup method

**Shortcut:** setup
**Available in:** Available in: C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
[NUnit.Framework.SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    $END$
}
```

Comment: Good point.  I can think of some cases where you might want to subclass test fixtures (perhaps if you wanted to write "contract" tests where a set of assertions should apply to a number of objects), but I think in the much more common case, virtual is superfluous.  I'll edit it out.

Comment: An improvement to this............private $classUnderTestType$ _classUnderTest;

[NUnit.Framework.SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _classUnderTest = new $classUnderTestType$($END$);
}

Answer (score 4):

### NUnit Teardown method

**Shortcut:** teardown
**Available in:** Available in: C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration is allowed

```
[NUnit.Framework.TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    $END$
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### New C# Guid

*Generates a new System.Guid instance initialized to a new generated guid value*

**Shortcut:** csguid
**Available in:** in C# 2.0+ files

```
new System.Guid("$GUID$")
```

**Macros properties**:

- **GUID** - New GUID - False

Comment: Recent versions of ReSharper now include the _nguid_ shortcut by default.

Comment: True, but it only generates a guid value, not initialize the type in C#.

Answer (score 3):

### Create sanity check to ensure that an argument is never null

**Shortcut:** eann
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type statement is allowed

```
Enforce.ArgumentNotNull($inner$, "$inner$");
```

**Macros:**

- **inner** - Suggest parameter - #1

**Remarks:**
*Although this snippet targets open source .NET [Lokad.Shared](http://rabdullin.com/projects/lokad-shared/) library, it could be easily adapted to any other type of argument check.*

Answer (score 3):

## New COM Class

**Shortcut**: comclass

**Available in**: C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration or namespace declaration is allowed

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("$GUID$")]
public class $NAME$ : $INTERFACE$
{
    $END$
}
```

**Macros**

- **GUID** - New GUID
- **NAME** - Editable
- **INTERFACE** - Editable

Comment: Nice template, but this might be better suited to a file template rather than a live template.

Answer (score 3):

## Assert Invoke Not Required

Useful when developing WinForms applications where you want to be sure that code is executing on the correct thread for a given item.  Note that `Control` implements `ISynchronizeInvoke`.

**Shortcut**: ani

**Available in**: C# 2.0+ files statement is allowed

```
Debug.Assert(!$SYNC_INVOKE$.InvokeRequired, "InvokeRequired");
```

**Macros**

- **SYNC_INVOKE** - Suggest variable of `System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke`

Answer (score 2):

### Trace - Writeline, with format

Very simple template to add a trace with a formatted string (like Debug.WriteLine supports already).

**Shortcut:** twlf
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where statement is allowed

```
Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("$MASK$",$ARGUMENT$));
```

**Macros properties:**

- **Argument** - `value` - EditableOccurence
- **Mask** - `"{0}"` - EditableOccurence

Answer (score 1):

## **New Typemock isolator fake**

**Shortcut**: fake
**Available in**: [in c# 2.0 files where statement is allowed]

$TYPE$ $Name$Fake = Isolate.Fake.Instance();
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => $Name$Fake.)

Macros properties:
    * $TYPE$ - Suggest type for a new variable
    * $Name$ - Value of **another variable** (*Type*) with the first character in lower case

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm working with Unity right now, I've come up with a few to make my life a bit easier:

---

### Type Alias

**Shortcut**: ta
**Available in**: *.xml; *.config

```
<typeAlias alias="$ALIAS$" type="$TYPE$,$ASSEMBLY$"/>
```

---

### Type Declaration

This is a type with no name and no arguments

**Shortcut**: tp
**Available in**: *.xml; *.config

```
<type type="$TYPE$" mapTo="$MAPTYPE$"/>
```

---

### Type Declaration (with name)

This is a type with name and no arguments

**Shortcut**: tn
**Available in**: *.xml; *.config

```
<type type="$TYPE$" mapTo="$MAPTYPE$" name="$NAME$"/>
```

---

### Type Declaration With Constructor

This is a type with name and no arguments

**Shortcut**: tpc
**Available in**: *.xml; *.config

```
<type type="$TYPE$" mapTo="$MAPTYPE$">
  <typeConfig>
    <constructor>
        $PARAMS$
    </constructor>
  </typeConfig>
</type>
```

etc....

Answer (score 1):

**log4net XML Configuration Block**

You can import the template directly:

```
<TemplatesExport family="Live Templates">
  <Template uid="49c599bb-a1ec-4def-a2ad-01de05799843" shortcut="log4" description="inserts log4net XML configuration block" text="  &lt;configSections&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;section name=&quot;log4net&quot; type=&quot;log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/configSections&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;log4net debug=&quot;false&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;appender name=&quot;LogFileAppender&quot; type=&quot;log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;param name=&quot;File&quot; value=&quot;logs\\$LogFileName$.log&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;param name=&quot;AppendToFile&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;param name=&quot;RollingStyle&quot; value=&quot;Size&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;param name=&quot;MaxSizeRollBackups&quot; value=&quot;5&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;param name=&quot;MaximumFileSize&quot; value=&quot;5000KB&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;param name=&quot;StaticLogFileName&quot; value=&quot;true&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;layout type=&quot;log4net.Layout.PatternLayout&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;        &lt;param name=&quot;ConversionPattern&quot; value=&quot;%date [%3thread] %-5level %-40logger{3} - %message%newline&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;/layout&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;/appender&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;appender name=&quot;ConsoleAppender&quot; type=&quot;log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;layout type=&quot;log4net.Layout.PatternLayout&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;        &lt;param name=&quot;ConversionPattern&quot; value=&quot;%message%newline&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;/layout&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;/appender&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;root&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;priority value=&quot;DEBUG&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;      &lt;appender-ref ref=&quot;LogFileAppender&quot; /&gt;&#xD;&#xA;    &lt;/root&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;/log4net&gt;&#xD;&#xA;" reformat="False" shortenQualifiedReferences="False">
    <Context>
      <FileNameContext mask="*.config" />
    </Context>
    <Categories />
    <Variables>
      <Variable name="LogFileName" expression="getOutputName()" initialRange="0" />
    </Variables>
    <CustomProperties />
  </Template>
</TemplatesExport>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Make Method Virtual

Adds virtual keyword. Especially useful when using NHibernate, EF, or similar framework where methods and/or properties must be virtual to enable lazy loading or proxying.

**Shortcut:** v

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ file where type member declaration is allowed

```
virtual $END$
```

The trick here is the space after virtual, which might be hard to see above. The actual template is "virtual $END$" with reformat code enabled. This allows you to go to the insert point below (denoted by |) and type v:

```
public |string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Equals

*Neither .NET in general nor the default “equals” template make it easy to bang out a good, simple Equals method. While [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509965/writing-a-good-c-sharp-equals-method) [are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [many](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Equality-Overloading-DotNET) [thoughts](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.aspx) on how to write a good Equals method, I think the following suffices for 90% of simple cases. For anything more complicated — especially when it comes to inheritance — it might be better [to not use Equals at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510092/27581).*

**Shortcut:** equals
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ type members

```
public override sealed bool Equals(object other) {
    return Equals(other as $TYPE$);
}

public bool Equals($TYPE$ other) {
    return !ReferenceEquals(other, null) && $END$;
}

public override int GetHashCode() {
    // *Always* call Equals.
    return 0;
}
```

**Macros properties**:

- **TYPE** - Containing type name - Not Editable

Answer (score 0):

### Rhino Mocks Record-Playback Syntax

**Shortcut**: RhinoMocksRecordPlaybackSyntax *

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files

**Note:** This code snippet is dependent on MockRepository (`var mocks = new new MockRepository();`) being already declared and initialized somewhere else.

```
using (mocks.Record())
{
    $END$
}

using (mocks.Playback())
{

}
```

*might seem a bit long for a shortcut name but with intellisense not an issue when typing.  also have other code snippets for Rhino Mocks so fully qualifying the name makes it easier to group them together visually

Answer (score 0):

### Rhino Mocks Expect Methods

**Shortcut**: RhinoMocksExpectMethod

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files

```
Expect.Call($EXPECT_CODE$).Return($RETURN_VALUE$);
```

**Shortcut**: RhinoMocksExpectVoidMethod

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files

```
Expect.Call(delegate { $EXPECT_CODE$; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Drew Noakes excellent idea, here is an implementation of invoke for Silverlight.

**Shortcut: dca**

**Available in: C# 3.0 files**

```
if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { $METHOD_NAME$(sender, e); });
    return;
}

$END$
```

**Macros**

- `$METHOD_NAME$` non-editable name of the current containing method.

Answer (score 0):

### Machine.Specifications - Because of

As a heavy mspec user, I have several live templates specifically for MSpec. Here's a quick one for setting up a because and catching the error.

**Shortcut:** bece
**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration or namespace declaration is allowed

**bece - Because of (with exception catching)**

```
Protected static Exception exception;
Because of = () => exception = Catch.Exception(() => $something$);
$END$
```

Answer (score 0):

### Machine.Specifications - It

**Shortcut:** it

**Available in:** C# 2.0+ files where type member declaration or namespace declaration is allowed

```
Machine.Specifications.It $should_$ =
    () => 
    {

    };
```

**Macros properties** (if present):

- **should_** - (No Macro) - EditableOccurence