# What do YOU use ReSharper for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, refactoring, automation, resharper

I'm in the middle of an ASP.NET MVC project and recently installed the free trial of [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) 4.5. Immediately I realized the benefits, simply because of the refactoring it wanted me to do.

Things like inverting `if` statements to reduce nesting, changing some of my `if`/`else` statements that were returning Views to `?`/`??` operators - drastically reduced the number of lines of code in my application.

The capability of performing a null reference check from a single click, removing unused directives/variables or removing redundant code (calling .ToString() when it wasn't necessary). Or, that it can see into my views to let me know I'm accessing a property that no longer exists, makes solution-wide renames more thorough... really saves a lot of time.

***But I get the feeling that I'm only seeing the tip of the iceberg.*** So I ask this:

What do **YOU** use ReSharper for? Anything beyond the immediate benefits I described above?

Comment: This is programming related and should not be closed! There is no shortage of dumb stuff to close!

Comment: I think the vote to close came from someone that wanted this to be community wiki, if you want it to be wiki, flag it for moderator attention or leave a comment saying: jeez I'd love to upvote this if it were community wiki.

Comment: Does "general badassery" count? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ReSharper provides a huge set of tools beyond the simple refactorings it suggests. In addition to providing additional code auto-formatting capabilities, ReSharper provides an integrated unit test runner that works with all of the known unit-test frameworks (such as NUnit, MBUnit, and my personal favorite, XUnit.NET). ReSharper also provides a very powerful template-based code generation platform that can improve your productivity by leaps and bounds.

For a full list of all the capabilities ReSharper can offer you, check here:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html

- [Code Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html#Live_Templates)
- [Navigation and Search](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html)
- [Unit Testing](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html)

Comment: Could someone explain what the down vote was for?

Comment: Oh man, the screenshot of the Code Templates link shows a join "snippet" for LINQ. Very cool... gonna have to get used to this.

Comment: About the down vote, no idea... I up-voted it. :D

Comment: @Chad: ReSharper is definitely THE programmers toolkit to get. It completely changed the way I write code...and I've been writing code since I was 8. Enjoy the wonderful new world of ReSharper! :D

Comment: I love this tool. I wouldn't consider programming in Visual Studio without it. The code templates are very helpful. As an example I've got two on my website if your interested: http://jarloo.com/tips-tricks/resharper-live-templates/

Comment: Basically R# is useless. Comparing to overhead it adds those small extra features are not worth it.

Comment: Vote Down: no really answering question. What has Resharper that VS is really missing? Nothing.

Answer (score 6):

What don't I use it for is more like it. Here's a shortlist of my most often-used shortcuts:

- Running unit tests. Their GUI unit test runner is awesome (sort by project/namespace is great), and I shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to run a test.
- Adding a class for unit tests, templated out with live templates
- Multiple custom livetemplates for filling in code, [especially complex attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186970/what-resharper-4-0-live-templates-for-c-do-you-use/639618#639618)
- Weeding dead code on our enterprise codebases
- Converting properties to auto-properties
- Combining variable declarations with their setup code
- Making methods static that can and should be static
- Looking at the pre-compilation errors/warnings bar saves me tons of time
- [StyleCop for ReSharper](http://www.codeplex.com/StyleCopForReSharper) puts all my styling warnings inline for me.

Pretty much most of these are done with just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The time saved is incalculable.

Answer (score 3):

Geez, where to begin?

- Refactoring.
- Code formatting.
- Code templates.
- Marker bar (the red/yellow/green stripes in the sidebar to show code warnings).
- Highlighting of unused code.
- Code generation.
- Shortcuts to save typing (for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to remove unneeded braces, change visibility, etc.)
- Code browsing. (Find References, Class Hierarchy, etc.)
- Unit testing.
- I could go on...

If you want a thorough overview of what ReSharper can do, check out my blog series, *[31 Days of ReSharper](http://blog.excastle.com/2007/01/31/blog-event-the-31-days-of-resharper/)*. It's missing the latest and greatest features (it was written for ReSharper 2.5), but it shows a lot of ReSharper in action.

Comment: Nice blog series... ty for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to keep the headers of each file up to date in an open source project.  By headers I mean license text.

Answer (score 1):

I used a really early version and found that it became really annoying when you were typing and the silly thing paused while it loaded the [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelli-sense).

No key strokes were lost, but the pause annoyed me to no end.

Has this been fixed or not?

So at the moment my answer is I don't.

Comment: yes.. much better in 4.5

Comment: ah good.  i might re-evaluate it for this place then.  thanks [me]

Answer (score 0):

I use ReSharper for:

1. Creating fields automatically.
2. Generating classes and methods (while doing [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)).
3. Automatically adding namespaces.
4. Finding usages.
5. Solution wide background compilation.
6. Templates to standardize conventions among a team.

Comment: Ah yes, automatic fields, auto namespacing...

What sort of templates do you use?

Comment: we standardize on conventions with variables (member and argument variables).  also there are addin like agent smith to have resharper show errors when you dont follow other rules as well

Comment: Nice.. I suppose since I'm developing alone at the moment that the templates could simply be used as code snippets of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework), you might be interested in the new ReSharper 5 beta. It adds some nice features specifically.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click navigation, find usages and refactoring from 'magic strings' ActionLink to Controllers/Actions.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click navigation find usages for your Views referenced in your controller actions, and to the partial views referenced in your views.
- Displays errors (even solution wide) when your ActionLink references a non-existing Controller/Action and allows you to automatically create stubs for it.

Comment: We also provide Intellisense for Actions, Controllers, User Controls, etc.