# Properly Implement Equals and GetHashCode in Sub Class

Tags: c#, equals

Let's assume I have the following Abstract Class Student:

```
public abstract class Student
{
    public string studentID {get; private set;}
    public string FirstName {get; private set;}
    public string lastname {get; private set;}
    public int age {get; private set;}

    public Student(string id,string firstname, string lastname, int age)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public abstract void calculatePayment();

}
```

and the following sub-class:

```
public class InternationalStudent:Student
{
    public bool inviteOrientation {get; private set;}

    public InternationalStudent(string interID,string first, string last, int age, bool inviteOrientation)
        :base(interID,first,last,age)
    {
        this.inviteOrientation = inviteOrientation;

    }

    public override void calculatePayment()
    {
       //implementation left out
    }
```

}

Main

```
InternationalStudent svetlana = new InternationalStudent("Inter-100""Svetlana","Rosemond",22,true);

InternationalStudent checkEq = new InternationalStudent("Inter-101","Trisha","Rosemond",22,true);
```

**Question:**

How would I **properly** implement my equalsTo method inside my subclass? I've been [reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509965/writing-a-good-c-sharp-equals-method) but I'm confused because some answers indicate that a subclass shouldn't know the members of the parent class.

If I wanted to implement IEquality in a subclass, so that `svetlana.Equals(checkEq);` returns false, how would I go it?

As per the comments what makes the object equals is if the ID, First name, and Last name are the same.

Comment: You are not specifying the conditions in which `Equals` will return true and the condition where it will return false. Please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused because some answers indicate that a subclass shouldn't know the members of the parent class.

You have that backwards. A subclass has complete knowledge of all non-private parent class members.

> How would I properly implement my equalsTo method inside my subclass?

What defines "equality" in your subclass?  Typically it's a combination of property values, but most of the pertinent properties are on the parent class, so would two "students" with the same first name, last name, age be "equal"?

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var student = obj as InternationalStudent;

    if (student == null)
    {
        return false;
    } 

    return this.FirstName == student.FirstName &&
           this.lastname  == student.lastname &&
           this.age       == student.age;
}
```

However, since all of the [properties in question are inherited, perhaps this belongs on the parent class instead of the sub class.

Comment: Many thinks for this. I quickly created this example to illustrate my problem. I should have put a student ID in the parent class now that you mention the same names.  The override Equals would be in the InternationalStudent class right?

Comment: I could also check to make sure that the object passed was a IS object before casting, correct?

Comment: @Svetlana `as` makes sure that the object is an appropriate type.  Use whatever properties makes two objects "equal".  If ID fits that description the use that.

Comment: One more question, should the abstract class have a equalsTo as well, or just the sub class?

Comment: You _could_ create an equals method on the base class that compares its properties, and call it from the base class, but it's not required.

Comment: Just to reaffirm then I'll drop it, the code you provided goes inside InternationStudent class right?

Comment: Since it checks to make sure the input is a `InternationalStudent` then yes.

Comment: If I wanted to add IEquatable, do I put in the subclass or the abstract class? so InternationalStudent:IEquateable<InternationalStudent>  or Student:IEquateable<Student>. My guess is the InterS would take the IEquatable because that way you can check all the members.

Answer (score 2):

Define Equals in base class, then call it from the child class

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    var other = obs as InternationalStudent;
    return other!= null && base.Equals(obj) && other.inviteOrientation == this.inviteOrientation;
}
```