# Useful Resharper Live Templates?

Tags: templates, resharper

What are some useful live templates for Resharper that you use on a daily basis?

Comment: Sorry Philip, there's no live templates for IL :)

Comment: I know. I don't need templates for IL; Console.WriteLine and ILdasm is all I need :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What ReSharper 4.0 live templates for C# do you use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186970/what-resharper-4-0-live-templates-for-c-do-you-use)

Answer (score 4):

I use a whole host (>1000) of live templates for creation of general-purpose structures *a la* CodeRush. You can find them [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6374633/CommonLiveTemplates.xml)

Comment: link to templates is dead

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom template for creating test methods that I use all the time.

```
[Test]
public void $TEST_NAME$() {$END$}
```

And also in conjunction with a custom file template for creating the test fixture.

```
using NBehave.Spec.NUnit;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Moq;

namespace $NAMESPACE$
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class $CLASS$ : TestBase
    {
        $END$
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This saves some typing for me, it creates a NUnit TestCase stub that handles exceptioncases:

```
[TestCase("arg1", "arg2", "expected", typeof(Exception))]
public void $TestName$(string $arg1$ , string $arg2$, string $expected$, Type expectedExceptionType)
{
if(expectedExceptionType!=null)
{
    Assert.Throws(expectedExceptionType, () =>
                                                {
                                                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Do something to trigger exception here!");

                                                });
}
else
{
    Assert.That("actual", Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
}
```