# creating custom templates in visual studio & resharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, resharper, resharper-6.0

I would like to create custom templates for c# files, unit test classes, .aspx.cs etc so that common items to all files are included once they are created eg file headers. I am working with visual studio 2010 and resharper 6. What is the easiest way to create these files and is it possible to be able to share them a team of developers easily? Appreciate any assistance or information as to how I might achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio templates are simple enough to create - you can distribute them to your colleagues to setup in the same location on their computers (or even create an installer, if you want to makes things even easier).

See [Creating Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx) and the [Introduction to Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx) on MSDN.

> #### Contents of a Template
>
> All project and item templates, whether installed together with Visual Studio or created by you, function by using the same principles and have similar contents. All templates contain the following items:
>
> The files to be created when the template is used. This includes source code files, embedded resources, project files, and so on.
>
> One .vstemplate file. This file contains the metadata that provides Visual Studio the information it needs to display the template in the New Project and Add New Item dialog boxes and create a project or item from the template. For more information about .vstemplate files, see Visual Studio Template Metadata Files.
>
> When these files are compressed into a .zip file and put in the correct folder, Visual Studio automatically displays them in the My Templates section of the New Project and Add New Item dialog boxes. For more information about template folders, see How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates.

Answer (score 0):

You should open Templates Explorer from `ReSharper | Templates Explorer`. Then select the File Templates tab. There are default templates that comes with ReSharper. You can examine them and see how you can write your own. Here's the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html#File_Templates) and there's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186970/what-resharper-4-live-templates-for-c-sharp-do-you-use) for useful examples.